# Altering data type in SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, alter-table

My current table has `OrderTime` datatype listed as `int`. However I require to change it to date/date time.

I tried altering the column's datatype using this `alter` statement:

```
Alter table Orders Alter Column OrderTime date;
```

but I get this error:

> ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
>
> 1735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify data type in Oracle with existing rows in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28791470/how-to-modify-data-type-in-oracle-with-existing-rows-in-table)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, I think a column needs to be empty to change the type.  So, something like this:

```
alter table Orders rename column OrderTime to old_OrderTime;

alter table Orders add column OrderTime date;

update Orders
    set OrderTime = old_OrderTime;

alter table Orders drop (old_OrderTime);
```

Comment: should be `rename column OrderTime TO old_OrderTime;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following (if column is empty or contains NULLs only)

`alter table Orders modify (OrderDate date);`

If column is not empty

```
alter table Orders
  add( new_date_col date );

update Orders
   set new_date_col = to_date(old_date_col, 'DDMMYYYY') // or other correct format
// 'DDMMYYYY' will work if you current number row contains 01012010

alter table orders
 drop column old_date_column;

alter table orders
 rename column new_date_col TO old_date_col;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use following solution

```
ALTER TABLE `Orders` CHANGE `OrderTime` `OrderTime` DATE NOT NULL;
```

For more help view my blog [99techguru.com](http://www.99techguru.com)